# Search queries returning 404

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, search, 404

If searching for a product that has a category, e.g. "Acer", "apple", "hp". It returns a 404 error not found.

This happens because URL rewrites are not on, and so the URL is `www.**.com.au/brands/acer` instead of `www.*.com.au/index.php/brands/acer`

Is there any work around to get this working WITHOUT enabling URL rewrites as it is not currently working with my shared hosting provider.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, in URL Rewrite management, it had search terms "Acer", "apple"...etc linking to the wrong URL. I added /index.php/ to each URL which fixed it.